# Which Java library ExtentReportManager is

Tags: java, selenium

I've run accross this piece of code somewhere in the internet:

```
ExtentReportManager reportManager = ExtentReportManager.createInstance();
```

I was googling half a day to find out which library (maven) this ExtentReportManager is from.
I'm using Maven + Java + Selenium + extentreports

My pom file dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

No code yet

Comment: This class can be found in these repositories:

https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=com.github.autoexsel

Comment: Thanks, Andew. I've added both dependencies, now my IDE "sees" ExtentReportManager but ExtentReportManager.createInstance() still not compiling.

Comment: Either wrong lib or I'm doing something wrong

Comment: it's not a popular library, you need to write `new ExtentReportManager()`, but I doubt it's the type you want.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me you have to create that class on your own. As an example: https://github.com/sopan-test/SampleSelenium/blob/79b5a5a7129bc99a947ce791ab32f37bade5860d/src/main/java/utils/reporter/ExtentReportManager.java

Comment: Thanks everyone. Finally decided to go without this thing. Used Reporter instead

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think there no method named **createInstance**  by default. you have to define it yourself like in this code.

https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/issues/1104

I hope it will help you :)